# Progress Bar does not work dynamically in angular 8

Tags: angular, mean-stack

I'm trying to upload the pic using the progress bar. The file is uploading properly but the progress bar is not working dynamically. I have researched on the web about try to follow their logic but I'm stuck. My progress bar what does is it simply show 100% directly even if file upload takes 2 or 3 secs. it is not progressing as progress bar does. Thanks in advance

---

AdminDashboard.ts file

```
onSubmit(){

    if (this.BannerForm.invalid){
        return
    }
    else{
        console.log(this.BannerForm)
        this.api.addImage(this.BannerForm.value.avatar).subscribe((event:HttpEvent<any>)=>{
            switch(event.type){

                case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
                    this.progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
                    console.log(`Uploaded! ${this.progress}%`);
                break;

                case HttpEventType.Response:
                    console.log(event)
                    this.snackbar.open(event.body.message, 'Success', {
                        duration:2000,
                        horizontalPosition:'left',
                        verticalPosition:'bottom'
                    })
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.progress = 0;
                      }, 1500);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

AdminDashboard.html File

```
  <form method="POST" (ngSubmit)='onSubmit()' [formGroup]='BannerForm' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label class="custom-file-upload">
        <input type="file" name="avatar" formControlName='name' (change)="uploadFile($event)"/>
            File Upload
        </label>

     <div *ngIf="progress > 0">
        <mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" [style.width.%]="progress" 
            value="{{progress}}"></mat-progress-bar>
      </div>

       <div class="my-3">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
       </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: is console print the uploaded percentage over here?

Comment: yes, it shows 100% straightaway. @ArunkumarRamasamy

Comment: so you mean there is no in between percentage value from 0 to  100?
Is it right what i understood? @Karan Dutta

Comment: yes. I have checked on various websites to do in between percentages they use Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total); which I have used. But don't know why I get straightway 100%. @ArunkumarRamasamy

Comment: In your develper console, you can minimise your internet speed. Are you try it out?

Comment: No, I didn't try that. But how it will solve my progress bar dynamic value problem? @ArunkumarRamasamy

Comment: If the Internet has slow. Your uploaded file took sometime to upload in server. In the meantime you can the get dynamic value.

Comment: How can I minimize internet speed in console? @ArunkumarRamasamy

Comment: inspect your web page -> go to network tab -> there is online/offline/fast 3g/slow 3g options are available you can choose slow 3g ant try it out

Note: In chrome browser

Comment: yeah, it starts showing 44%, 87%, 100%. when chosen slow 3g. But when I choose online it waits till the response come from the backend holds on 100% form 1 or 2 secs. @ArunkumarRamasamy

Comment: I thought you need check this with api services from backend.